"segno.QRCode has no attribute to_artistic" error
I have a weird issue where "qrcode-artistic" works when executing the python code as it is (as code by using 'python mycode.py'), BUT it does not work if I compile the code using pyinstaller. (And pyinstaller does not return any error).
I'm running Python 3.11.9 with segno 1.5.2 and qrcode-artistic 2.1.0.
I confirm qrcode-artistic ins installed as the code works when not using the .EXE file.
      File "ORIGINAL_code.py", line 349, in <module>
      File "ORIGINAL_code.py", line 323, in main
      File "segno\__init__.py", line 970, in __getattr__
    AttributeError: <class 'segno.QRCode'> object has no attribute to_artistic
[7552] Failed to execute script 'ORIGINAL_code' due to unhandled exception!
'''

Line 349 calls the main() block.

Lines 322 and 323 have this code:

qr = helpers.make_wifi(ssid, guestPsk, security)
qr.to_artistic(background='green.png', target='QR-CODE.png', dark='#012A2D', data_dark='#003F2D', data_light='white', scale=8)



There is absolutely nothing in your code that indicates to pyinstaller that the qrcode_artistic module is even used by your program - there is some deep magic going on in segno, that turns the lookup of the nonexistent to_artistic method into a dynamic import of the plugin module.  I'm not that familiar with pyinstaller, but it certainly has some way of telling it to include specific modules, even in the absence of an explicit import (any module that has auto-loaded plugins would need to use this).
